# Crossover technique in a genetic algorithm

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, genetics

I am in the process of writing a small genetic algorithm framework in C++. My chromosomes are encoded as bit strings, where each gene has a predetermined size. Each chromosome stores its genes one after the other in the bit string. Now, I am looking to implement the crossover operator.

My question is, when choosing a point after which to insert bits from the other chromosome, do I do this on a gene boundary or do I just treat the chromosome as a string of bits, and ignore the division into genes? In other words, do I treat the smallest swappable unit as a gene or a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two chromosome reproduce together, there is a random probability of the gene crossover. Therefore, you should only cross what you consider genes instead of the smaller units.

Comment: So I use gene boundaries and always swap entire genes, not bits. That's simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: I've implemented it in Python to place Voltage Regulators at optimal locations on distribution networks using CYME. It was however not sufficiently effective compared to the basic "sequential algorithm".

Comment: I would say this is odd. Correct me if I'm wrong but I would not say the body – when reproducing – has a way of knowing where a gene starts and ends. Therefore I would suggest treating the smallest unit as a allele and not a gene.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this query would best be understood by looking at the biological processes on which GA is based.

Assuming what you're looking for is a single-point crossover, what you would need is as illustrated below; crossovers affect the entire chromosomes and not just "the smallest swappable unit".

[image]

Details about more complex crossover scenarios such as multi-point crossover or ring crossovers may be found at the Wikipedia resource [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosomal_crossover).